# How to programmatically hide and show status bar in iOS 13?

Tags: ios, ios13, uiapplication, uistatusbar

I have made following common method for hiding and showing again status bar. It works fine before iOS 13, but I am getting following crash while I run it for device having iOS 13 or greater.

```
+(void)showStatusBar:(BOOL)show
{
    UIView *statusBar = [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] valueForKey:@"statusBarWindow"] valueForKey:@"statusBar"];

    if ([statusBar respondsToSelector:@selector(setBackgroundColor:)]) {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:!show withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationNone];
    }
}
```

**Getting following error for iOS 13**

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'App called -statusBar or
>   -statusBarWindow on UIApplication: this code must be changed as there's no longer a status bar or status bar window. Use the
>   statusBarManager object on the window scene instead.'

What can I do to hide and show status bar for some view controllers only?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621440-prefersstatusbarhidden

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to show/hide the status bar on the different View Controllers you need to:

1. Add **View controller-base status bar appearance** option in your Info.plist and set it to **YES**
2. Override `var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool` in each View Controller where you want to have the status bar shown/hidden

```
override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool { 
  return true 
}
```

If you want to show/hide it dynamically (ex. after tapping on button), you could do something like this:

```
var statusBarHidden = true {
  didSet {
    setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate()
  }
}

override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool { 
  return statusBarHidden 
}
```

- You could find more verbose explanation here [Here](https://medium.com/@craiggrummitt/the-mysterious-case-of-the-status-bar-d9059a327c97)
- Also in the [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uistatusbarmanager) for `UIStatusBarManager` you can find the following quote:

> You do not use this object to modify the configuration of the status bar. Instead, you set the status bar configuration individually for each of your UIViewController objects. For example, to modify the default visibility of the status bar, override the prefersStatusBarHidden property of your view controller.

Comment: @coolcool1994 That's weird. Could you double check if you've completed *step 1: Add "View controller-base status bar appearance" option in your Info.plist and set it to YES*. Without it there will be no difference