# Cannot hide status bar in IOS 13

Tags: statusbar, ios13, uistatusbar

In IOS 11 and 12 I have used

`[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] valueForKey:@"statusBarWindow"] valueForKey:@"statusBar"]`

to hide the status bar by changing the height. In IOS 13 using **statusBarManager** can get the **statusBarFrame** and change the height but it's not getting changed in the view. Does anyone know how to change the status bar frame in the IOS 13?

Answer (score 0):

If you need the status bar frame only to show/hide it, there is more correct way to do it by overriding the `var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool` for the interested View Controllers

Please review my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59275412/1611876) for more detailed explanations.

Though, if you still need the status bar frame for any other reason, you could obtain it in your View Controller like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57023907/1611876)

```
let statusBarManager = view.window?.windowScene?.statusBarManager
let height = statusBarManager?.statusBarFrame.height ?? 0
```